# Special characters handling in Java String

Tags: java, php, json

i've to retrive this [type of] string from a website :

```
{"title":"En Loz\u00e8re, les entreprises sont incit\u00e9es \u00e0 passer \u00e0 la fibre","author":"Fran\u00e7ois Le Gall","date":...
```

I'd like to have an object like this :

```
myObject{
  String title = "En Lozère, les entreprises sont incitées à passer à la fibre";
  String author = "François le Gall";
  ...
}
```

This is the way i retrieve my String in java :

```
String myJsonString = "";
    try{

        URLConnection conn = new URL("http://www.ariase.com/webservices/getArticle.php?id=3019").openConnection();

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(in);
        s.useDelimiter("\\A");

        while (s.hasNext())
            myJsonString += s.next();

        s.close();
        in.close();

    } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    RssJsonObject myParsedJsonObject = RssJsonObject.parseJson(myJsonString);
```

It's a Json Object i have to parse, no problem, but i've this specials characters like `\u00e0` which i don't know how to replace...

I can do a dozens of `replaceAll("\u00e0", "à");` but, is there any pre-build function to do that?

I can also edit the php page wich send me this string, maybe i've forgotten any `url_encode` or something, i'm pretty bad at php.

This is my php code :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM SITE.rssitem WHERE NEWSID = '".$newsId."'";

$eligibiliteDB->request($query);

$answer = $eligibiliteDB->first();

$tab =  array(
    "title"         => strip_tags($answer['TITLE']),
    "author"        => strip_tags($answer['AUTHOR']),
    "date"          => strip_tags($answer['DATE']),
    "img"           => strip_tags("http://www.ariase.com/fr/news".$answer['MINIATURE']),
    "description"   => strip_tags($answer['DESCRIPTION']),
    "content"       => strip_tags($answer['FULLDESCRIPTION'].' '.$answer['CONCLUSION'])
);

echo json_encode($tab);
```

EDIT :

My Java code above.

I don't know if my mistakes come from the java or the php part.
And i'm knew with all this encoding stuff, don't understand it very well, just know that i don't want to see `\u00e8` but 'è' in my application! :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any replacement. The JSON parser should handle it all for you. It's not clear where Java comes into this, by the way...

Comment: php create the webpage with this string for articles i've to display in an android app. The Java part is to handle this string and display it properly in my app.

Comment: Well, \u00e0 is the Unicode notation for your character. I would think you have some enconding mismatch at some point. You would have to further describe what charsets you are using at each app layer (including db) and at which point you are seeing the \u00e0 instead of the "small letter a with grave".

Comment: @eduine: But what has Java got to do with your question? It's really unclear whether you're asking for help with the PHP part or the Java part. If it's the Java part, why haven't you shown any Java code?

Comment: Which library are you using? Whis is RssJsonObject? I don't get any problems with Gson `Map o = new Gson().fromJson(data, Map.class);` (instead of Map you can use your class).

Comment: `RssJsonObject` is a personal class i made myself to handle json objects i retrieve with the string.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java source the escaping `"\u00e0"` is actually identical with `"à"`, for the Unicode character U+00E0 LETTER A-A_GAUCHE. You might find such escapes also in JavaScript and JSON data. Reading it as JSON object should give a String object with the correct Unicode `à`.

Should for some reason you get 6 characters `\u00e0` then something should be done differently.

However you can also continue, and convert it back using the class [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache commons.

```
String s = "\\u00e0"; // How one would represent the six chars \,u,0,0,e,0.
s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s);
```

BTW `in.close()` is not needed as `s.close()` also closes `in`.